# Syntax error when trying execute dynamic query which contain dollar quoting to escape nested single quotes

Tags: postgresql, dynamicquery, dollar-quoting

I have following piece of code, which does following

- Generate set of string column names when provided a date range which are simply dates between the range
- Then this function is used within an another function to generate dynamic query string
- Next generated dynamic query string used with `EXECUTE`

As I notice syntax error occour at `EXECUTE` statement, I have already tried different variation of dollar quoting without success.

```
DROP EXTENSION IF EXISTS tablefunc;
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS tablefunc;


DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS app_public.generate_date_columns(p_from_date DATE, p_to_date DATE);

-- Step 2: Create a function that generates the dynamic SQL query
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION app_public.generate_date_columns(p_from_date DATE, p_to_date DATE)
  RETURNS TEXT AS $$
DECLARE
  column_names TEXT := '';
  pay_date DATE;
BEGIN
  -- Generate column names and select columns
  FOR pay_date IN SELECT generate_series(p_from_date, p_to_date, '1 day'::interval)::DATE LOOP
    column_names := column_names || format('"%s" INT,', pay_date);
  END LOOP;

  -- Remove the trailing commas
  column_names := substr(column_names, 1, length(column_names) - 1);

  RAISE NOTICE 'Columns: %s', column_names;

  RETURN column_names;
END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


SELECT app_public.generate_date_columns('2023-05-30'::DATE, '2023-06-05'::DATE);


DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS app_public.incentive_per_line(DATE, DATE);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION app_public.incentive_per_line(p_from_date DATE, p_to_date DATE)
  RETURNS SETOF RECORD AS $$
DECLARE
  column_names TEXT;
  v_dynamic_query TEXT;
BEGIN

    SELECT app_public.generate_date_columns(p_from_date, p_to_date) INTO column_names;

    SELECT  FORMAT($tag$'SELECT * FROM crosstab($ct$'SELECT op.line_no::SMALLINT, pay.payout_date::DATE, pay.amount::INT AS incentive
    FROM app_public.operators AS op INNER JOIN app_public.payouts AS pay ON pay.oid = op.id
    WHERE pay.payout_date >= date($from$'%s'$from$) AND pay.payout_date <= date($to$'%s'$to$)'$ct$) AS ct(ln SMALLINT, $cn1$%s$cn1$)'$tag$, p_from_date, p_to_date, column_names)
    INTO v_dynamic_query;

    RAISE NOTICE '%s', v_dynamic_query;

   EXECUTE v_dynamic_query;

END
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


select app_public.incentive_per_line('2023-05-30'::DATE, '2023-06-05'::DATE);
```

I want dynamic query to execute successfully without any syntax errors. Additionally appreciate If you help me to improve this dollar quoting experience.

Syntax Error:

```
[42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "'SELECT * FROM crosstab($ct$'" Where: PL/pgSQL function app_public.incentive_per_line(date,date) line 16 at EXECUTE
```

Comment: Could you narrow it down to the part with the error? Could you tell us what the error is, exactly?

Comment: @NickBarnes added the exact syntax error to the post

Comment: Can anyone please explain why there are down votes?, down voting result in question not being exposed to interested audience.

Answer (score 0):

The error message shows the failing syntax, specifically, the single `'` preceding `SELECT`.

```
[42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "'SELECT * FROM crosstab($ct$'" Where: PL/pgSQL function app_public.incentive_per_line(date,date) line 16 at EXECUTE
```

The `SELECT` statement was already quoted by `$ct$`, so the additional single `'` is part of the string instead of quoting the string.

Comment: Thank you for the response, I removed `'` now I am getting another syntax error. when fixed there is an another and so on. This is lot of things to go wrong here: strings argument for where clause, column names with series of double quoted strings.